# Ruby on Rails UrlGenerationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

This may be a very stupid question. I'm very new to Ruby, and thus have no idea what I'm doing. 
I'm setting up a layout in application.html.erb. One of the links for my navigation is just supposed to link to a default show page for a resume. I should have probably set it up as an index instead of show. But when I tried that, things just got even more confusing.

With the code I currently have, the error I'm getting is

```
Showing thisSectionOfUrlTakenOut/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb 
where line #22 raised:

No route matches {:controller=>"resume", :action=>"show"} missing required keys: 
[:id]


Extracted source (around line #22):

19   <ul>
20   <li><%= link_to "Home", welcome_index_path %></li>
21   <li><%= link_to "Projects", projects_path %></li>
22   <li><%= link_to "Resume", resume_path, method => show %></li>
23   <li><%= link_to "Blog", posts_path %></li>
24   </ul>
25   </nav>
```

As is, my application.html.erb looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <title>Portfolio</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", 
"data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application", 
"data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<header>

  <% if current_user %>
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <%else%>
      <h1> Portfolio</h1>
  <%end%>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><%= link_to "Home", welcome_index_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Projects", projects_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Resume", resume_path, method => show %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Blog", posts_path %></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>

<%= yield %>

<footer>
  <% if !current_user %>
      <%= link_to "Login", admin_console_index_path%>
  <% else %>
      <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete%>
  <%end%>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

The routes.rb looks like

```
Portfolio::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

  resources :projects

  resources :resume

  resources :admin_console

  resources :welcome

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

And the resume_controller.rb looks like

```
class ResumeController < ApplicationController
  def show
  end
end
```

If it helps, some of the issues started when I started using devise. But since then, I think other errors have made things worse. I would be extremely grateful for any help. If you could explain it to me, that would be better

Comment: Are you going to have multiple resumes saved in the db, or is this a personal website where you would only ever show your own?

Comment: Did you create the resume through a form in your website or just through html by hand??

Comment: the resources is expecting an id to show a specific resume  as @jstim askes are you going to have more then 1, or do you just want /resume to show *your* resume?  if the former, you need to pass a resume object (or an id into resume_path)

Comment: I'm running low on time, so for now I'm just hard coding a resume into the html. When the class ends, I'll go back through and probably create a resume to put into the db and then create crud pages for it. But for right now, I can't do that. I can only hard code for now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your routes. You are defining `resources :resume` which implies that there are many resumes and thus when you want to link to a resume you have to know its id.

What you should do instead is:

```
get '/resume' => 'resume#show'
```

Also remove the `method => show` option in your resume link. It is not needed an will probably cause an error once you fix the routes.